# R: Is there a way to count the number of consecutive numbers in each row?

Tags: r

I'm wondering if there's a way to count the number of consecutive numbers in each row. 
Ideally, the output will be in column V6 and count the number of consecutive numbers in columns V1-V5.

For example, Row 1 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 since there are 5 consecutive numbers, the output will be 5. I've attached the dataset that I have below for your reference.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7az4.png)

Comment: Hi VH214. Welcome to Stack Overflow! If possible, could you edit your post, delete the image, and replace it with a "copy and pastable" version of your data (or a small subset) so others can attempt to __reproduce__ your problem. Sound reasonable to you? Then your question will get a whole lot more attention and in a whole lot less time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option where we get the difference between alternate columns by removing the first column, last column, convert to a logical matrix (`== 1`) and get the `rowSums`

```
rowSums((df1[-1] - df1[-ncol(df1)]) == 1) + 1
#[1] 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = 1, V2 = 2, V3 = 3, V4 = 4, V5 = 5:14)
```